# What is the difference between variable and function in function parameter?

Tags: javascript

How to distinguish the name of a function (callback) from the variable given in the function parameter in JS?
The variable specified in the parameter and the function can have any name.
How do I know it's a function and not a variable?
If we pass a function as a parameter, we do not use ().

For example:

```
function someFunction(someNameVar, someNameCallbackFunction){
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You can't distinguish it. There's nothing to meaningfully distinguish, even: it's a variable _and_ (its value is) a function.

Comment: You can use `if (x instanceof Function)` (with a few caveats for weird situations)

Comment: @Pointy I don't think they want to distinguish the value in code, they want to know how they're supposed to know to provide a callback function.

Comment: You read the documentation. It should say what the argument should be.

Comment: The same way you know whether some other argument should be a number, string, object, etc.

Comment: You can't. Usually, if a function accepts a callback as a parameter, then it is the last parameter of that function. But it's just a convenience, not a solid rule

Comment: Since the parameter name contains "callback", that's a strong suggestion that it should be a function.

Comment: Perhaps best way to distinghuish if a function param is a variable or a callback function is using Typescript because then you'll have intellisense telling you that you cannot use `()` to call a variable

Comment: @Barmar yea, but who knows for sure?

Comment: @Pointy I do. My magic power is discerning what people are actually asking in confusingly-worded questions.

Comment: Same as how you distinguish a string variable from a number variable: by naming conventions and by documentation. Or, if it needs to be dynamic at runtime, by using `typeof`.

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript does not do any type checking, you cannot fully know what type each parameter is when writing the code. Instead, you can use a language like TypeScript to explicitly define and infer types at compile time (although it does not do type checking at runtime).

Should you want to do some sort of logic based on the type, `instanceof` (classes or functions) or `typeof` (simple types) is likely your best bet.

Comment: Rather, `typeof` not `instanceof`

Comment: True, but it depends on the usage - I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks!